# Is it possible to convert ASP.NET MVC4 web application into executable file in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a mvc4 application in visual studio 2012, is it possible to convert this application into executable file?

like [VS 2005 Web Deployment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx)

Any help and guidance is appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible to convert this application into executable file?

No, this is not possible and hardly makes any sense. An ASP.NET MVC application needs to be hosted on a web server.